Find the Major Axis, Minor Axis, and Rotation Angle of an Affine Transformed Ellipse
I have an ellipse defined by its major axis a, minor axis b, and rotation angle θ.

I need to apply an affine transformation to this ellipse. The affine transformation includes scaling and rotation but no translation.

Given the transformed ellipse, I want to determine the following parameters:
The new major axis a'
The new minor axis b'
The new rotation angle θ'

Could someone provide a detailed explanation or step-by-step method to compute these parameters from the affine-transformed ellipse? Any mathematical derivations or Python code examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

@Futurologist maybe you can help on this one too :)

Please [edit] the question to tell us what data you start with that describes the affine transformation you are applying.

If you define your ellipses by the lengths of their axes and their angles of rotation, how can you be "given" the transformed ellipse without being told the new major axis, new minor axis, and new rotation angle? If the ellipse is specified in some other way, we need to know what way that is.
